# how to explode a string with "|"

Tags: php

I have this string `S|http://www.xyz.in`, and want to explode this into

Array(0)--> `S`

Array(1)--> `http://www.xyz.in`

Please Help I am new to php

Comment: What you have tried/searched so far? where you are getting problem?

Comment: I have tried using explode('\',$str); But as \ is used as escape i am unable to split it

Comment: Does your string `S|http://www.xyz.in` have \? and you can explode with \\ for this

Comment: Sir I tried with \\ but it dint worked for me...

Comment: @AkshayBajpei Read my update

Comment: I dint found any update related to what i was looking for ... can you help me?

Comment: @Akshay Bajpei - Please explain "how you got it solved". Assuming Ravi Hirani's suggestions were helpful and/or reflected the solution, be sure to upvote - and, if you choose, accept - his response.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$str = 'S|http://www.xyz.in';
print_r(explode('|',$str));
```

OR

```
$str = "S|http://www.xyz.in";
$chunks = spliti ("\|", $str, 5);
print_r($chunks);
```

OR

```
$str = "S|http://www.xyz.in";
$chunks = preg_split("/\|/", $str);
print_r($chunks);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the escape character.

```
explode('\\\\',$str);
```

If you want to split by the `|` (like you show in your example), use `explode('|',$str)`

Comment: I tried this before asking here.. It dint worked

Comment: I dint found any update  related to what i was looking for ... can you help me?

Comment: Probably not.  Have you tried everything listed here?

Comment: Done.. I got it solved..